# htacces url-rewrite for multiple variables

Tags: .htaccess

I have the following url-rewriting in htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^category/([0-9]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/?([0-9a-zA-Zßäöü\s]+)?/?([0-9a-zA-Z.ßäöü\s]+)?/?([0-9a-zA-Z.ßäöü\s]+)?/?([0-9]+)? category.php?mid=$1&cid=$2&ccid=$3&cccid=$4&ccccid=$5&page=$6 [NC,L]
```

category/$1/$2 should open catagory.php?mid=$1&cid=$2 (and will start with page=1); this works fine with the above code.

However, I would like the following url's to work as well"
category/$1/$2/$6 should open category.php?mid=$1&cid=$2&page=$6.

Please note $6 is always a number, the categories $2, $3, $4 and $5 are a combination of numbers and letters.

Examples:

- `category/19/sport (mid=19, cid=sport)`
- `category/19/sport/2 (mid=19, cid=sport, page=2)`
- `category/19/sport/soccer/2.championsleague/2016results (mid=19, cid=sport, ccid=soccer, cccid=2.championsleague, ccccid=2016results)`
- `category/19/sport/soccer/2.championsleague/2016results/10 (mid=19, cid=sport, ccid=soccer, cccid=2.championsleague, ccccid=2016results, page=10)`

How should I alter the URL rewrite?

Comment: @ anubhave, some examples added.

Comment: How come `cccid` parameter showing different values for same URL?

Comment: my fault, that should have been ccccid. I have corrected it above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use these rule in your site root .htaccess:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

# skip all rules below for real files and directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^category(\d+)/([^/]+)/?$ category.php?mid=$1&cid=$2 [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteRule ^category(\d+)/([^/]+)/(\d+)/?$ category.php?mid=$1&cid=$2&page=$3 [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteRule ^category(\d+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ category.php?mid=$1&cid=$2&ccid=$3&ccccid=$4&cccccid=$5 [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteRule ^category(\d+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/(\d+)/?$ category.php?mid=$1&cid=$2&ccid=$3&ccccid=$4&cccccid=$5&page=$6 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: @ Anubhave, is there a possibility that I leave the ^category out, so my URL looks like
`19/sport/soccer/2.championsleague/2016results (mid=19, cid=sport, ccid=soccer, cccid=2.championsleague, ccccid=2016results)`

instead of

`category/19/sport/soccer/2.championsleague/2016results (mid=19, cid=sport, ccid=soccer, cccid=2.championsleague, ccccid=2016results)`

Comment: Ye just remove category/ from all rules above. I am on mobile so unable to make edits.